# NetBeans xliff plugin

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins, xliff

I'm editing the `xliff` file with NetBeans editor in a Symfony2 project.

It's not so bad but i would like to know if somebody know / exist a plugin for NetBeans for a better edit of this kind of files.
I've already seen some separated editors, then, the question concern only NetBeans' plugin.

Thanks in advance